# Does tuple sort itself when looped through

Tags: python

I have a tuple which contains multiple values which I use for searching in some file. I get this tuple as an input parameter to my method. I try to search for that value(text) in one file and returns related result. But I have a requirement that if that text is not found then search for the value **'Unknown'** in that file and return corresponding value. To achieve this I am planning to append value **'Unknown'** to the tuple so that if it doesn't find anything, it will return something corresponding to **'Unknown'**. But my question is that if I apeend **'Unknown'** at last, while looping through this tuple does it loop through in the same order which the elements were added to it? I have tried it on python shell and noticed that it loops through it in the same order. But I don't want my code to accidentally search for **'Unknown'** value before desired ones. Please help.

Comment: you can't change tuple.

Comment: Tuples are ordered, so it will search for it in the order of the elements. Is order important? Typically in search it doesn't matter which order the key is found, as long as its found. I also think you can optimize your code using dictionaries where the key is the lookup and the value is the result (the corresponding value). This will make your lookups faster as well.  You should post the code you are using to help with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over a tuple always goes from the first element to the last.

```
>>> for x in ('asdf', 5, None):
...     print x
...
asdf
5
None
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `tuple`, I think you mean `list`. Tuples don't have an append operation, they are fixed in size.

If you append to a list while iterating, you'll get the expected result. It's **not good practice**, however, to alter a collection while walking it.

A much better approach is to collect items to be appended in a second list, and concatenate the two lists when you finish iterating the first.

Comment: They don't have an append, but that doesn't mean you can add to them. You just need to create a new tuple (just like a string). `a = (1,) b = a+(2,)`

Comment: I hope he is not doing that :( I'm not even sure I understood the question right